# Get taxonomy based on another taxonomy slug

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have 2 custom taxonomies associated with 'property' custom post type.

1 - prop-city

2 - prop-type

can i get property type based property city?

I need in properties city page when i click on property type link show me the property types in same city by property city slug.

now i'm displaying property cities like this

```
$terms = get_terms(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'prop-type',
                'parent' => 0,
            )
        );
```

And i can get the current page property city slug by:

```
get_query_var( 'term' );
```